# Creating new Page in Sharepoint Designer Workflow created blank page ( no banner, no office 365 bar etc...)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, online

When I create a new page in the Sharepoint Designer Workflow by using the action " Create item in Site Pages" and choosing Content Type ID ="Web Part Page" it created a new page like expected but the page is completly blank... No Office 365 bar, no banner nothing. Is there a trick in solving this or do I need to use a different Workflow Action?